# Query from two db tables with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

Table 1:

```
PRESETS
- id
- image
- url
- name
- collectionID
```

Table 2:

```
COLLECTION
- id
- collection_name
```

I'm trying to print with PHP a thing like:

```
COLECTION NAME
Image1 image2 image3 image4 image5

COLECTION NAME2
Image1 image2 image3 image4 image5
```

and so on...

I'm trying to figure out how to make this code run. It doesn't print anything...

```
<?php
            $sql = "SELECT collection.id, collection.name
    FROM `collection`
    ORDER BY collection.id DESC";
$categories = $mysqli -> query($sql);
foreach($categories as $cat) {
echo '<li><a href="#">' . $cat[1] . '</a><ul>';
$sql2 = "SELECT presets.preview, presets.seoName
        FROM `presets`
        WHERE `presets`.collectionID = ".$cat[0];
$products = execute_select($sql2);
foreach($products as $prod) {
    echo '<li><a href="&id=' . $prod[1] . '">' . $prod[0] . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul></li>';
}
            ?>
```

But I can't figure out how to get data as described above. What kind of query can I make?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about JOINs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT image, name, url, collectionID 
FROM presets 
INNER JOIN collection on (collection.id=presets.collectionID)
ORDER BY presets.id DESC
```